# Webdevelopment in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am somewhat familiar with Scheme. I am reading OnLisp, and would love to do a real world project in it. Most likely web development. I would love to know what kind of setup people use to develop websites in lisp. I have a couple of macs at home and I have figured I would use clozure cl. I am wary of a few things though. I have read on the internets that cl doesn't have reliable threading facility nor good networking. Is this true? What was your experience?

PS:Don't tell me about clojure :). Lisp is a itch I need to scratch.

Comment: Also, most of the web applications that were out there seem a bit antiquated. I'm not saying "Haha.. look ma.. no clothes", but can anybody tell me why this is the case, or show me a counter example? Also, are there any lisp to javascript translators out there. Is there any help from lisp on the front end?

Comment: I suspect it's a social issue.  Since there are relatively few Lispers, Lisp-based web applications generally don't have a lot of contributors.  Therefore, developers tend to have to focus on getting the basics done and neglect things like flashy AJAX features.

Comment: To fellow googlers: I suggest to have a fresher look at the [awesome common lisp](https://codyreichert.github.io/awesome-cl/) list !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why it wouldn't have "good networking"; you can't rely on threads if you want to write a portable Common Lisp application since certain implementations don't support them (AFAIK, just [`clisp`](http://www.clisp.org/), though you can compile it with experimental thread support). If you plan on picking an implementation and sticking with it, you won't have that problem.

The "standard" CL web stack is [Hunchentoot](http://weitz.de/hunchentoot/)/[cl-who](http://weitz.de/cl-who/)/[clsql](http://clsql.b9.com/), though you can find tutorials that run on [Araneida](http://www.cliki.net/araneida) or [Portable AllegroServe](http://portableaserve.sourceforge.net/).

The setup I use is [Debian](http://www.debian.org/)/[SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/) running [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/) and the above systems along with MySQL (though I'm seriously considering jumping over to [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/)) for the database and [nginx](http://nginx.org/) to run in front of Hunchentoot serving any static content.

Comment: I tried using SBCL on mac, but I get "threading disabled" error when I tried to load weblocks. I enabled threading, but it still says the same darn thing :). Anyways, I will stick to clozure for now. Thanks for all the info. I think this is a good start.

Comment: @Ravi In my experience, SBCL and Clozure CL are very similar in the way they behave, so using the latter is unlikely to cause any problems.  I tend to us Clozure CL on Mac OS X and SBCL on GNU/Linux, for instance, and I have yet to encounter any portability issues between the two.  (CLISP and ECL are another matter entirely, of course, but when writing web apps, I simply ignore their existence. :))

Comment: By the way, in addition to the libraries mentioned in this answer, I suggest looking into [Postmodern](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/postmodern/) for your database needs.  I have found it to be very flexible and predictable.

Comment: Thats good to hear about SBCL and clozure. I was thinking if I should get a linux box. I will postpone it until I run into performance issues.

Comment: configuring clsql is painful, and takes a lot of time (especially if you're using it on multiple platforms and implementations, like I did). In contrast, postmodern (using PostgreSQL) "just worked" on all platform/implementation combinations, and talks to the server directly via TCP/IP, in contrast from clsql which uses CFFI/UFFI and sometimes needs additional libraries, sometimes Unicode doesn't work (and you can't find help online, I tried), so Postmodern is more reliable. I speak from real experience as I've used both commercially.

Answer (score 8):

Currently I'm using [Restas](http://restas.lisper.ru/en/) a framework based on `Hunchentoot` and inspired by the route system of Rails. I also use [Postmodern](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/postmodern/) to interact with a `PostgreSQL` database and I generate HTML with [cl-markup](https://github.com/arielnetworks/cl-markup) though I'm thinking about switching to [cl-who](http://weitz.de/cl-who/) which looks more customizable.

When I've started I've also considered using [Parenscript](http://common-lisp.net/project/parenscript/) to generate the `JavaScript` but now I'm just happy with [Mootools](http://mootools.net/) and plain `JavaScript`.

Everything runs on SBCL and is available with Quicklisp.

Comment: Parenscript looks interesting. Your setup looks comprehensive. Thank you.

Comment: I've been playing with Restas for a while now. Why i like it: 1) As the name suggests it encourages restful design 2) Its simple, if you think in terms of MVC its pretty much just the C part, and done pretty well. 3) Its very flexible 4) I find its concept of routes superior to the way Django does its dispatch using regular expressions(although i think it got that good idea from rails) 5) You can structure your site in modules and then mount them at specific urls, again, superior to Djangos way of organizing apps in a project of using a spaghetti bow of url.py files. 6) its lisp :)

Answer (score 3):

mck- has been maintaining the heroku common lisp webapp.

https://github.com/mck-/heroku-cl-example/tree/

Answer (score 2):

The problem with Common Lisp's "networking" is, we don't have sockets in CL standard, so each implementation has it's own socket API. We have some attempts to give a common interface though, like `usocket`. You can find a list of networking related packages [here](http://www.cliki.net/networking).

If you need a web framework, look into [Caveman](https://github.com/fukamachi/caveman). I haven't used it yet but it looks like the most complete CL web framework I've ever seen.